# skew detection and reduction in opencv

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing, skew

I've been working on a project that involves several preprocessing on a scanned document. Part of this preprocesses is *skew detection and correction* . Before skew detection and correction i have a binarization process going on for the document image.

I would like to see some projects or sample codes. Thanks !!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some time ago I found a blog that had 2 interesting posts on this subject:

- [Detect skew angle](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-detect-skew-angle/)
- [Rotation (Deskew)](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-rotation-deskewing/)

These posts also share the source code.